# How to print a word document using spire.doc?

Tags: c#, spire.doc

I'm creating a WPF application and I want print a word document using spire.doc. I read some tutorials and they say that I should use this code.

```
//Create Word document.
Document document = new Document();
document.LoadFromFile(@"..\..\..\..\..\..\Data\Template.docx");
//Print doc file.
System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog();
dialog.AllowCurrentPage = true;
dialog.AllowSomePages = true;
dialog.UseEXDialog = true;
try
{
document.PrintDialog = dialog;
dialog.Document = document.PrintDocument;
dialog.Document.Print();
}
```

But it doesn't work because `document.PrintDialog` type is `System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog` and I get this error:

> cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog' to
>   'System.Windows.Controls.PrintDialog'

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use `Document.PrintOut()` [documentation can be found here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/document-printout-method-word/)

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Spire.Doc.Wpf.dll** to print Word document in WPF applications. Refer to the following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.LoadFromFile(@"Test.docx");
        PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();

        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            dialog.PrintDocument(doc.PrintDocument.DocumentPaginator, "test");
        }
    }
```

If my answer helps, please mark it as answer, thanks :)